# Angular HttpInterceptor for caching parallel request by sharing the observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

i want caching HTTP parallel request by sharing the observable and also cache the response in a Map object.

[demo online](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jqlthz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcaching-interceptor.service.ts)

**caching-interceptor.service.ts**

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, finalize, share } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class CachingInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  public readonly store = new Map<string, HttpResponse<any>>();
  public readonly queue = new Map<string, Observable<HttpEvent<any>>>();

  constructor() {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    // Don't cache if it's not cacheable
    if ( req.method !== 'GET' ) {
      return next.handle(req);
    }

    // Checked if there is pending response for this request
    const cachedObservable: Observable<HttpEvent<any>> = this.queue.get(req.urlWithParams);
    if ( cachedObservable ) {
      console.info('Observable cached');
      return cachedObservable;
    }

    // Checked if there is cached response for this request
    const cachedResponse: HttpResponse<any> = this.store.get(req.urlWithParams);
    if (cachedResponse) {
      console.info('Response cached');
      return of(cachedResponse.clone());
    }

    // If the request of going through for first time
    // then let the request proceed and cache the response
    console.info('Request execute');
    const shared = next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          console.info('Response reached');
          this.store.set(req.urlWithParams, event.clone());
        }
      }),
      finalize(() => {
        // delete pending request
        this.queue.delete(req.urlWithParams);
      }),
      share()
    );

    // add pending request to queue for cache parallell request
    this.queue.set(req.urlWithParams, shared);

    return shared;
  }
}
```

Is this implemplementation of observable caching correct?

**I'm some doubt about: what happening if the observable is deleted into finalization of the request and some has subscribed?**

*Side Note: this is just an example and don't implement cache expiring/invalidation.*

Comment: Regarding your question, if you worry about a memory leak, I'd this is not the case. I've detailed this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63258734/9632621).

Comment: My worry is about the subscription itself. In this case the subscription become undefined in the middle of the request, and maybe the subscriber never receive the  result of subscription. Is a bit tricky.. but the point is if delete from map, destroy the referenze of the subscription object.

Comment: Now if I have a closer look, I think the subscribers will receive the values, since `finalize()` is called after completion/error. Have you tried it and got a different result? Maybe a StackBlitz demo would help

Comment: I don't succeeded to create a demo for investigating the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You implementation works fine, but I think it can be made much simpler.

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { shareReplay, first, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class CachingInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  public readonly store: Record<string, Observable<HttpEvent<any>>> = {};

  constructor() {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    // Don't cache if it's not cacheable
    if ( req.method !== 'GET' ) {
      return next.handle(req);
    }

    // Check if observable is in cache, otherwise call next.handle
    const cachedObservable = this.store[req.urlWithParams] ||
      ( this.store[req.urlWithParams] = next.handle(req).pipe(
          // Filter since we are interested in caching the response only, not progress events
          filter((res) => res instanceof HttpResponse ),
          // Share replay will cache the response
          shareReplay(1),
      ));
    // pipe first() to cause the observable to complete after it emits the response
    // This mimics the behaviour of Observables returned by Angular's httpClient.get() 
    // And also makes toPromise work since toPromise will wait until the observable completes.
    return cachedObservable.pipe(first());
  }
}
```

Check my [Stackblitz fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lvyp8p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcaching-interceptor.service.ts)

Comment: The issue with this approach is that you are not cloning the cached response. So any modifications to the data will also update the data within the cache. How can you incorporate the cloning of the response so any modifications made will not affect the data in the cache?