# Memory leak when Observable source object got destroyed

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

What happen when you subscribe to `observable`, then the source of this observable is no longer used in application? Is there any memory leak? I have `FormArray` which have some of `FormGroup`. I subscribe for every of `FormGroup.valueChanges`, and do I need tu unsubscribe when `FormGroup` is removed from `FormArray`? Same goes to `Subjects`, do i need to unsubscribe to them if for some reason I would have `Subject` in for example `Component` and this component will be destroyed? I've read this answer [Angular/RxJs When should I unsubscribe from `Subscription`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription) but there is nothing about my case.

Comment: For me, I unsubscribe always to be extra safe. To "finish" a subject, call `.complete()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there is no need to unsubscribe. It won't do any harm if you do, but I don't think it's necessary.

You can find a more detailed explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63257763/do-subscriptions-to-rxjs-subjects-cause-memory-leaks-if-not-unsubscribed-when-th/63258734#63258734).

But the gist is this: in this case, the memory leaks occur when the subscriber created from the `subscribe`s' callback is still part of the `Subject`'s subscribers list. This means that when the component will be created again, another subscriber of that type will be added to the list, while the old one is still there. That's why the memory leak occurs.

However, if you unsubscribe, that subscriber won't be part of that subscribers list anymore. The reason I'd say there is no need to unsubscribe in this case it because the only thing that would still reference that subscriber, the `Subject` instance, which is what prevents that *old* subscriber from being garbage collected, will be nulled out. My reasoning is: if what keeps that subscriber *alive* is nulled out, then there is no way that subscriber's next callback can be reached again, so it can be garbage collected.