# Angular memory optimization with NgRx store to avoid memory leaks

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, rxjs, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am a part of an enterprise application in Angular 11. We use the NgRx store heavily and I was wondering if we can improve our application memory footprint by optimizing the subscriptions (currently the **memory footprint** is around **~200-220 MB** and **live JS Heap** size **~76-85 MB**).

To us, performance optimization is really important, as our clients don't refresh or close the browser window throughout the day and since we have enough subscriptions to serve our clients I need help to keep the memory footprint below the accepted limits and to not impact our clients.

We use subscriptions in the following manner:

```
private destroyed$: ReplaySubject <boolean> = new ReplaySubject(1);


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.accountProgress$ = this.store.pipe(select(appState => appState.account.accountProgress), takeUntil(this.destroyed$));
    ...
    ...
    this.accountProgress$.subscribe(() => {...})
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroyed$.next(true);
    this.destroyed$.complete();
}
```

Likewise, we have many other observable subscriptions that listen to different parts of App State. I have few queries:

- Can the subscription `this.accountProgress$.subscribe(() => {...})` still cause a memory leak? If it is used multiple times within the same component to fetch data in different methods? Should we use `takeUntil()` or `take(1)` with this kind of subscriptions as well (we have this at few places but I am not sure if it helps)? Or make use of share operators such as `publish() + refCount()` or `share({refCount: true})` with `this.store.pipe(select(appState => appState.account.accountProgress))`?
- Sometimes we need to `dispatch` an action based on the value we receive within the subscription, I know that this is an **anti-pattern** that we should not `dispatch` an action within a subscription, but what can be done, as few stores depend on API response and that is quite uncertain when it will return the data which will decide the further execution of the business logic
- Are there any other ways to optimize? (Please note that we follow the aforementioned syntax of `takeUntil()` everywhere in our components wherever required, are there any other ways to prevent the memory consumption when dealing with NgRx store, Effects and Observables)

Comment: takeUntil is fine, in case you are trying to get rid of memory leaks. the problem is in something else. dispatching action inside of a subscription is probably better to move to effects. it shouldn't affect the performance anyhow, but at least it would look cleaner

Comment: Something I have noticed is that the "memory leak" in our application increases if the Redux dev tools extension is enabled. Try disabling it and see what the performance is like with it disabled.

Comment: @AliF50 the shared stats are on a normal system without any redux extension :)

Answer (score 2):

> Can the subscription `this.accountProgress$.subscribe(() => {...})` still cause a memory leak?

A while ago, I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63257763/do-subscriptions-to-rxjs-subjects-cause-memory-leaks-if-not-unsubscribed-when-th/63258734#63258734) an answer that describes why memory leaks occur when using a Subject in RxJS. So, in this case I'd say it won't, because you're using `takeUntil(this.destroyed$)`.

> If it is used multiple times within the same component to fetch data in different methods?

If `takeUntil` is still there, there won't be any memory leaks. But, there is an important aspect that you should be aware of.
Suppose you have a subject which has a few subscribers:

```js
const s = new Subject();

const o1$ = s.pipe(
  a(),
  b(),
  c(),
  d(),
);

const o2$ = s.pipe(
  a(),
  b(),
);
```

If you subscribe to `o1$` 3 times, there will be 3 **distinct instances** of each operator used until `s.pipe`, namely `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`. This might be something you'd want to avoid and you can do so by using `share()`, `shareReplay()` operators:

```js
const o1$ = s.pipe(
  a(),
  b(),
  c(),
  d(),
  share(),
);

// now, when `o1$` is subscribed, each of the `a-d` operators will have exactly one instance
o1$.subscribe()
o1$.subscribe()
o1$.subscribe()
```

> Should we use `takeUntil()` or `take(1)` with this kind of subscriptions as well

It depends, `take(n)` will complete after the `n-th` values has been emitted and `takeUntil(notifier$)` will complete when `notifier$` emits.

> Sometimes we need to dispatch an action based on the value we receive within the subscription ...

Maybe instead of doing this in the subscription, you can use the `tap` operator, which is well-known for side effects.

```js
data$ = this.store.select(yourSelector).pipe(
  /* ... */
  tap(result => this.store.dispatch(anAction))
  /* ... */
)
```

Also, the `data$` observable from above can be used in conjunction with the async pipe, so you don't have to deal with manual subscription/unsubscription.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth explanation :) @Andrei

Comment: It's been a pleasure to help!

Answer (score 1):

Your actual methods to handle subscriptions are great, but I think the best way to handle rxjs code in Angular is to use the async pipe and good data composition.

You have to think in all the data needed to render your component and combine it to get just one final observable to be subscribed in HTML, in that way you can take advantage of `ChangeDetectionStrategy` and `trackBy` for `*ngFor` with reactive data.

Follow these links to get a better undertanding:

- [Data Composition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z76QlSpYcck&t=7s)
- [RxJs Best Practices](https://blog.strongbrew.io/rxjs-best-practices-in-angular/)

Hope I helped you a little.